# Different math rendering in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, math-mode, amsmath, beamerposter

When using beamer for presentations, I notice that the rendering for math becomes quite different, and I really prefer the usual rendering, say, when typing a paper. The symbols look a bit less formal, and less aesthetically pleasing...

Is it possible to use the regular rendering of math symbols in the beamer package?

That is, I'd like:
[image]

to look more like:
[image]

Comment: You're probably looking for `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}`.

Answer (score 2):

Beamer uses sans serif math to match sans serif body fonts.

If you want serifs, say `\usefonttheme{serif}`.  If you want the math to be serifed, but the body to be sans serif, say `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}`

Comment: Just an observation: The [onlymath] option seems quite smooth and the math doesn't look alien or out of place compared to the surrounding text